# Unable to get the comment form in django using django comments framework

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I am trying to integrate django comment app with my own app named as 'blog'. However, when I am trying to get the comment form, I ma getting 'None' instead of the model form.

below is my "home.html" template code where I want my form to appear.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{%load comments%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Sourav's blog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    {%block styling%}
    <link href="{%static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{%static 'css/blog-post.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
    {%endblock styling%}

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ideate</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{%url 'blog_new_post'%}">New idea</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="{%url 'blog_login'%}">Login</a></li> -->
                    {{user.is_authenticated}}
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{%url 'blog_logout'%}">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{%url 'blog_login'%}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Hi {{user.username}}</a>
                    </li>
                    {%else%}

                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <!-- Blog Post -->

                <!-- Title -->
                <h1>Idea Blog</h1>

                <!-- Author -->
                <p class="lead">
                    by <a href="#">Ideate</a>
                </p>

                <hr>

                <!-- Date/Time -->
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 
                Posted on
                <!-- {%for i in blog_data%} 
                    {{i.posted_on}}
                {%endfor%}</p> -->
                {% for i in last_element %}                        
                    {{i.posted_on}}
                {%empty%}
                    <span>No data</span>
                {%endfor%}


                <hr>

                <!-- Preview Image -->
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt="">

                <hr>

                <!-- Post Content -->
                <!-- <p>Below is the result</p> -->
                <!-- <p>{{blog_data}}</p> -->
                <p>

                    <!-- {%for i in blog_data%}                        
                       <h1>{{i.title}}</h1> 
                       <p>{{i.description}}</p>  

                    {%empty%}
                        <span>No data</span>
                    {%endfor%} -->
                    <!-- {{last_element}} -->
                    {% for i in last_element %}                        
                        <h1>{{i.title}}</h1> 
                        <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                    {%empty%}
                        <span>No data</span>
                    {%endfor%}

                    {% get_comment_count for blog.blogpost 2 as comment_count %}
                    <p>{{ comment_count }} comments have been posted.</p> 

                    {% get_comment_list for blog.blogpost 1 as comment_list %}
                    {% for comment in comment_list %}
                    <p>Posted by: {{ comment.user_name }} on {{ comment.submit_date }}</p>

                    <p>Comment: {{ comment.comment }}</p>

                    {% endfor %}
                    {%get_comment_form for blog.blogpost as comment_form %}
                    <p>{{comment_form}}</p>

                    {% get_comment_form for blog.blogpost as form %}
                    <!-- A context variable called form is created with the necessary hidden
                    fields, timestamps and security hashes -->
                    <table>
                      <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
                            <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </form>
                    </table>


                </p>               


                <hr>
                <!-- Blog Comments -->

                <!-- Comments Form -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <!-- Posted Comments -->

                <!-- Comment -->
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Start Bootstrap
                            <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                        </h4>
                        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Comment -->
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Start Bootstrap
                            <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                        </h4>
                        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                        <!-- Nested Comment -->
                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Nested Start Bootstrap
                                    <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                                </h4>
                                Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Nested Comment -->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <!-- Blog Search Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Search</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input-group -->
                </div>

                <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>

                <!-- Side Widget Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Side Widget Well</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    {%block javascript%}
    <script src="{%static 'js/jquery.js'%}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{%static 'js/bootstrap.min.js'%}"></script>
    {%endblock javascript%}

</body>

</html>
```

below code from views.py is called when I hit my homepage "home.html"

```
def home(request):
    blog_data = BlogPost.objects.all()
    last_element = BlogPost.objects.filter(id = len(blog_data))
    context = {'blog_data':blog_data, "last_element":last_element}
    #last_element = list(BlogPost.objects.all().reverse()[0])
    print("last_element",last_element, "blog_data",blog_data,"context",context)
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    # Create your models here.
    class BlogPost(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        posted_by = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
        comment = models.CharField(max_length = 150) 
        tags = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = "notag")


        def __str__(self):
            #return "{0} : {1}".format(self.title, self.description)
            return self.title
```

[image]

Please help me out of this. Please let me know if any other information is required on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for `get_comment_form`](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/b8a4f8d16dacbd5fc2512fa8e566e9324492a323/django_comments/templatetags/comments.py#L303), looks like you have to include the `BlogPost`'s id when you use this tag:

```
{% get_comment_form for blog.blogpost last_element.id as comment_form %}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, however this did not work, rather threw error

Comment: Sorry missed to send the error "BlogPost matching query does not exist."

Comment: Okay, are you sure your `last_element` exists in your database?

Comment: Exception Type: DoesNotExist""BlogPost matching query does not exist"

Comment: What does `print("last_element",last_element, "blog_data",blog_data,"context",context)` display in your console?

Comment: last_element [<BlogPost: fifth idea>] blog_data [<BlogPost: my post>, <BlogPost:
 Second post>, <BlogPost: third post>, <BlogPost: Fourth post>, <BlogPost: fifth
 idea>] context {'last_element': [<BlogPost: fifth idea>], 'blog_data': [<BlogPo
st: my post>, <BlogPost: Second post>, <BlogPost: third post>, <BlogPost: Fourth
 post>, <BlogPost: fifth idea>]}

Comment: this is what it it prints

Comment: basically last_element is a variable to store the latest instance of BlogPost model

Comment: ok I see. The problem is that `last_element` is a `list`, not a `BlogPost`. If you want `last_element` to be a `BlogPost`, you have to assign it like this: `last_element = BlogPost.objects.filter(id = len(blog_data))[0]` (notice the `[0]` at the end)

Comment: You are fantastic ! Now I am able to see the form.